# Can I install Ubuntu using Ubuntu 13.04 Live CD on Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: installation, 12.10, 13.04, upgrade, live-cd

And, will may my applications be as is?
Am I going to have any compatibilty issues with applications?
Is it possible even using a live cd to install the newest version of Ubuntu over the existing one.

Comment: Do you want to upgrade from 12.10 to 13.04 using the 13.04 Live DVD/USB? Note 13.04 is too big to fit in a CD.

Comment: yes, but I have a slow internet connection, so I won't upgrade from the software updater

Comment: Yes you should get a prompt to upgrade when you boot from Live DVD and start the install process. Some applications will be upgraded and some may be. You will have to reinstall those applications. Your home folder and data should be preserved. However, to be safe make backup copies of your personal data, photos, music, videos, etc.

Comment: What is with these damn "possible duplicates", its so annoying. I searched for my problems before I ask them. Can't you just answer the damn question instead of marking it as a "possible duplicate"?

Anyways I think that that question's answer helped though @user68186

Answer (score 0):

You can use this guide to upgrade Ubuntu 13.04 from Ubuntu 12.10
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/upgrade

Comment: I want to know if its possible with a live cd, without losing my apps and configurations. And is there going to be any problems with my applications?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when you install there will be an option to install Ubuntu 13.04 keeping your old files and programs. However, some settings maybe reset. You should make a backup of any important data in case it get's lost in the upgrade.